# How can I move the clock and date to the bottom in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, top-bar

I want move the clock and date bar (where Wi-Fi, sound, battery information is displayed) to the bottom of the screen. Can I do that?
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUdrH.png) is my actual bar.
(My system is on Spanish so my browser is on Spanish too.)

Comment: You can use a different desktop environment. There are several with the characteristic you're asking for.

Comment: You could look at the **dash-to-panel** _gnome-shell-extension_: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/ The "**gnome-tweaks**" app complements it nicely, perhaps install that one as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options here, all requiring, obviously, to install a Gnome Shell extension.

- To do just what you want, i.e., move the bar to the bottom, install the extension [BottomPanel by abstract](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/949/bottompanel/). The extension [Just Perfection by JustPerfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) can do much more, but also includes an option to move the panel to the bottom. It is very well maintained and even works on the newest Gnome Shell 40.
- A more invasive change would be to use the extension [Dash to Panel by jderose9](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/). This changes the setup to something resembling that of Windows 10. The bar moves to the bottom, and also includes the dock.

Comment: Thanks, I will install the extension.

Comment: If this answer resolved your question, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the question.

Comment: Dash to Panel by jderose9 does not work on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Package gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gnome-shell-extension-dash-to-panel' has no installation candidate

Comment: [Dash to Panel by charlesg99][1] is the Extension. Works well on GNOME Shell 3.36.9 (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS)


  [1]: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the [Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org//extension/3843/just-perfection) extension
2. Open the Extension Manager from apps menu
3. Click on the gear button in front of Just Perfection
4. Navigate to Customize tab
5. Change Panel Position ✓