# How to change position of top bar in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: top-bar

I want to change position of ubuntu 20.04 top bar that displays time and other stuff is there any way to change its position to bottom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I move the clock and date to the bottom in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338761/how-can-i-move-the-clock-and-date-to-the-bottom-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
You may try Gnome extensions to move the panel to the bottom.
Try the extension [Bottom panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/949/bottompanel/)